# Crimson Guard v Explorator?

Tags: multi-classing, rogue-trader, dark-heresy-1e

Long story short, my Explorator was re-made into a Crimson Guard, and now I have the opportunity to "multi-class" as an Explorator again.

As a Crimson Guard, they are generally more "combat focussed", while Explorators are more "inquisitive".

As a Crimson Guard (as the primary character focus), is there any advantage to multi-classing as an Explorator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several references to the Crimson Guard.  The one I have come across the most are House Guards, a part of one of the Ecclesiarchy's sects (military) or part of the militant wing of the Adeptus Mechanicus.  They should, IMHO, draw more talents and skills from the Arch-Militant Class as that class focuses on combat.